# Why is my object rotating oddly?

Tags: modeling, animation, objects, keyframes, object-mode

https://youtu.be/ISEo-8k-6gg
I'm trying to animate a treasure chest, so I moved the origin to an edge, and now I cant rotate it properly. I know you can do this, but I don't know how I might've messed it up.

Comment: [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a link to a video](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this) While videos and images are helpful they should not be the only source of information, add some description of the issue along with some screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

Before adding keyframes you need to apply the rotation using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

You are experiencing a gimbal lock, which happens when two rotation axes coincide causing a loss of rotational freedom- in this case, the X and Z axes. This is because you have set the Y rotation value to 90, so applying it should solve the issue.

More on gimbal lock: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock

Answer (score 3):

This is Euler bad interpolation. You can easily fix this: Align your chest with the global orientation, parent it to an empty, rotate the empty so that the whole chest is orientated the way you want in the 3D scene, then keyframe the opening. Now that the chest is parented to the empty, its new global orientation is relative to the empty, not the world.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a gimbal lock. It appears with Euler rotation. Blender default is XYZ Euler. You need to use quaternion rotation. These can be chosen from pop-up menu under rotation angles.

Quaternion rotation is a bit more difficult but it is worth learning. You need it if you want to rotate something around more than one axis.